# How to increase maximum dependent item in Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

I get this error:
Cannot create item "kube.pod.containers.limits.cpu[***/###]": maximum dependent item count reached.
I think this parameter is set to 29999 in default. How can i increase this parameter?

Comment: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/dependent_items I guess this limit is in the code. Looks like a huge count ….

Comment: @ik_zelf I have much more dependent items. I think it is limited to 29999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardcoded in the source: release/6.0 zabbix_server/lld/lld_item.c

```
typedef zbx_lld_item_full_t zbx_lld_item_t;

  #define ZBX_DEPENDENT_ITEM_MAX_COUNT    29999
  #define ZBX_DEPENDENT_ITEM_MAX_LEVELS   3
```

So changing this requires a recompile and some testing. The limits sometimes have a reason.